# SublimeText 2 CodeIntel for PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext2, code-intelligence

Just installed [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) via PackageControll plugin on my Windows 7 x64 PC for the latest (v 2.0.1) SublimeText 2, and there has no effect when I try autocomplete simple class method 'foo':

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        public function foo($a) { echo $a; }
    }
    $f = new Foo();
    $f->
?>
```

Any suggestions?
P.S. Also .codeintel directory doesn't contain any log files and yes, I'd restarted SublimeText 2 after plugin install.

Comment: This is most likely OS related, as I can confirm that it does work for me on Mac OSX. I'd recommend posting the issue on the packages Git repo, or a post in the Sublime Text forums.

Answer (score 1):

yep there is issue with Sublime 2.0.1 
You need wait for CodeIntel update

Comment: Could you at least add a link to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to have been solved.

Manually Downloading the latest version of SublimeCodeIntel solved this issue for me. I basically deleted the "SublimeCodeIntel" folder from the Sublime\Data\Packages dir and cloned the entire repo directly from github into that folder and worked as expected! :)

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Answer (score 0):

Here's what got CodeIntel to work for PHP for me:

1. Delete all files under .codeintel/db/php (for Windows 7, it's at C:\Users\[name]\.codeintel\db\php)
2. Restart Sublime Text 2